# Как написать скрипт, который будет искать максимальное вхождение кодов в номер?(javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, sql, postgresql

Здраствуйте!

Есть таблица с такими столбцами и с такими значениями:

```
id  code   name    sign         money
1   8916   МТС     Сеть Мтс     1.29
2   7916   МТС     Сеть МТС     1.3
6   89998  Билайн  сеть Билайн  1.5
15  89999  Билайн  сеть Билайн  1.4
```

как сделать так, чтобы я вводил номер, например: 79169312751 и на вывод приходило это:

```
id  code   name    sign         money
253 79169  МТС     Сеть Мтс     1.7
```

Comment: *Есть таблица с такими столбцами* Где она есть-то? в каком виде/формате? массив, коллекция, список, внешний CSV, таблица в БД? что-то ещё?

Comment: таблица на PostgreSQL.

Comment: Мы не видим 79169312751 номер в примере данных. Это частичное сравнение? Пожалуйста, предоставьте дополнительные объяснения.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Тут в столбце `code` первые 5 цифр номера. Когда автор вводит номер, то нужно найти запись, `code`которой совпадает с 5 начальными символами номера.

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE  LEFT( parameter '79169312751', 5) = code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM source_table
WHERE '79169312751' ~~ (code || '%')
ORDER BY code DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее, что за операторы в секции `WHERE` используются?

Comment: @cauf `||` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html, `~~` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но javascript жалуется на синтаксис. была бы возможность, поставил бы, что "ответ полезен".

Comment: @thx *javascript жалуется на синтаксис* Ни разу не видел окна от javascript с текстом "Жалуюсь на синтаксис"... сообщая об ошибке, цитируйте полностью текст сообщения (не говоря уж о том, что следует показать воспроизводимый блок кода, приводящий к ошибке), ибо смысла в простой констатации факта - ноль. И, поскольку тут всё же не привычный форум для вдумчивого толковища, лучше открыть чат темы и постить туда.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно будет использовать реальный параметр в функции LEFT ().

**SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM source_table
WHERE LEFT( parameter '79169312751', 5) = code
ORDER BY code DESC
```

Comment: А кто сказал, что длина данных в поле `code` - строго 5 символов? даже в показанных данных это не так. И в ТАКОМ варианте применённая сортировка - более чем бессмысленна. И ключевого слова `parameter` в синтаксисе функции `LEFT()` - не имеется.

Comment: @Akina, (1) OP сказал это в комментариях: "...Тут в столбце code первые 5 цифр номера. Когда автор вводит номер, то нужно найти запись, code которой совпадает с 5 начальными символами номера...". (2) Мой пример кода SQL, LEFT() - псевдокод. Мы не знаем, как передается реальный параметр.

Comment: Вы посмотрите внимательнее, кто это сказал - и кто автор вопроса.